# Formdata not recognizing Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have built a Time Off Request application in React.js and I’m now adding the ability to insert comments by the requester. The new request form takes in values based on the employee that is logged in and the employee enters the date they want to take off along with the number of hours.

When the request is added to the request database, it takes in the employee id as a foreign key. I’m making a user input to be able to add a comment to the bottom of the new request page. The comment will be added to a separate database using the request id and employee id as foreign keys.

The code and the functions are working properly, but when the page is refreshed or reloaded, the employee id’s initial value is undefined because it is blank. I know that it’s a race condition that I’m running in to, but to this point, I have not found a solution.

I’ve tried using conditional rendering based on employee info and it comes back undefined. I’ve tried initializing the employee id after it’s been brought in through context with the same result and I’ve tried calling it as props directly into the form values. When I log the id value in the console, it is correct both before and after the formValues are declared.

Could someone tell me what I’m doing wrong?

```
//General Imports
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"

//Component Imports
import Navbar from "../../components/NavBar/NavBar";

// Context Imports
import { EmployeeInfoContext } from '../../context/EmployeeInfoContext';

//Hooks Imports
import useAuth from '../../hooks/useAuth';

const NewTimeOffRequestPage = (props) => {
    // setting up hooks a good place to start
    const [user, token] = useAuth ()
    const navigate = useNavigate ()
    const [approved, setApproved] = useState("False")
    // const {employee, setEmployee} = useContext(EmployeeInfoContext);
    const [requestId, setRequestId] = useState(null)

    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
        employee_id: props.employeeData.id,
        date_requested: '',
        hours_requested: '',
        approved: approved,    
    });

    const handleRequestSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pto_requests/new/`, formValues, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
        setRequestId(response.data.id);
        // await handleUpdateBalance(updatedPtoBalance);  
        const commentValues = {
            employee: props.employeeData.id,
            pto_request: response.data.id,
            text: '', 
        };
        console.log(commentValues)
        return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments/changes/', commentValues);
        // props.getAllComments()
        })
        .then(response => {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //handle error
            console.error(error);
        });
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
        };

    return ( 
        <div><Navbar />
        <div>{props.employeeData? 
            (<div className='request-table'>
                <form onSubmit={handleRequestSubmit}>
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b>Employee Number: </b></label>
                {props.employeeData.employee_number}
                </div>
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b>Employee Name: </b></label>
                {props.employeeData.employee_first_name + " " + props.employeeData.employee_last_name}
                </div>
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b>Department:</b> </label>
                {props.employeeData.department}
                </div>
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b>Hire Date: </b></label>
                {props.employeeData.hire_date}
                </div>
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b>PTO Balance:</b> </label>
                {props.employeeData.pto_balance}
                </div>
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b>Supervisor Name:</b></label>
                {props.employeeData.supervisor_number}
                </div>
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b>Date Requested Off: </b></label>
                <input type="date" name="date_requested" value={formValues.date_requested} onChange={handleChange}/>
                </div>
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b>Hours Requested: </b></label>
                <input type="number" name="hours_requested" value={formValues.hours_requested} onChange={handleChange}/>
                </div>                        
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b> Approved: </b></label>
                <input type="boolean" name="approved" value={formValues.approved} onChange={handleChange}/>
                </div>
                <div className='newEntry'>
                <label><b>Comments: </b></label>
                <input type="text" name="text" value={formValues.text} onChange={handleChange}/>
                </div>
                <div className='submit-new-request'>
                    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                    {/* <button onClick={handleCommentSubmit}>Submit Comment</button> */}
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>):(<div>NO DATA AVAILABLE</div>)}
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default NewTimeOffRequestPage;
```

I appreciate the help!

I’ve tried using conditional rendering based on employee info and it comes back undefined.

I’ve tried initializing the employee id after it’s been brought in through context with the same result and I’ve tried calling it as props directly into the form values.

When I log the id value in the console, it is correct both before and after the formValues are declared.